# Run a custom code after a product is sold in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, backend

I need to know how to assign custom actions (or run custom code) when someone buys something in the website and the payment has been completed. I need this so our system can send order's data to an API.
i am using wordpress and woocommerce for the website.
how can i find the order dynamics variable to put it in my API's code ?

if there,s anyone who use wordpress and woocommerce, please tell me where can i find order's dynamic variables such as:
product id which the customer has been ordered
product count and etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a function that connects to the `woocommerce_order_status_processing` hook. At this point, the payment has been accepted and WooCommerce is waiting for the store to fulfill the order.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'my_order_complete_function', 10, 1 );
function my_order_complete_function( $order_id ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    foreach($order->get_items() as $item) {
        $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
        $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
        
        // Add your API call here.
        
    }
}
```